# How do I use .last() with other aggregates in groupby to sort in date order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pandas-groupby

Can someone explain what I need to do, to sort this code in date order? 'DateAppeared'

```
mean_of_sold_price = houses_my_postcode_data.sort_values(by=['DateAppeared']).groupby(['NumberofBedrooms','MONTH','YEAR'])['SoldPrice'].last().mean().round()
```

I get **AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'round'**

```
mean_of_sold_price = houses_my_postcode_data.sort_values(by=['DateAppeared']).groupby(['NumberofBedrooms','MONTH','YEAR'])['SoldPrice'].mean().round().last()
```

I get **TypeError: last() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'**

I am trying to follow the example here, but my code has more groupby functions

[Sorting Pandas dataframe data within Groupby groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121344/sorting-pandas-dataframe-data-within-groupby-groups)

```
tempDF.sort(['id','date']).groupby('id')['status'].last()
```

As you will see from screenshot below my months are out of order, when I run code without trying to sort. How can I run code to put in correct date order?

[image: Months out of order]

Comment: Can you add example its not so clear what you want?

Comment: @adir abargil Thank you for your question, I have added a screenshot to illustrate the issue where I am trying to report number of sales in date order, Aug 2020 is showing before Jan 2020. The 'DateAppeared' column contains the dates even though it is not displayed in the groupby statement.